# Android - disable proximity sensor programmatically within a call

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximitysensor

I am developing an android application which can run with an active call, in this case the user needs the screen (he/she talks with a headsets).

The problem is the proximity sensor, if the user taps it the screen goes black, is there any way, from the code, programmatically, without rooting, in which I can disable this function?

Thanks.

=======================================================================
EDIT: From Mike Armstrong response, I tried this without success:

In activity onCreate():

```
// Disable proximity sensor.
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
sensorManager.registerListener(getSensorListener(), sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Listener:

```
private SensorEventListener getSensorListener(){

    return new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // nothing.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // nothing.
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: have you tried wakelock ? https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: This wakelock does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Checkout this...

`http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html`

Simply handling a listener to the proximity sensor should override it during your call, as long as you're not making a call with an intent. If you're making a call with an intent then you'll default to the android phone app and that will most definitely be out of scope in terms of your app.